# NCMB　の検索：IDで検索を行い、それがあるか否かを返す関数は？

Tags: unity3d

ニフティクラウドモバイルバックグラウンドとUnityです。

固有のIDを使って得点を記録します。
既に得点がある場合には問題ないのですが
初回の処理「そのIDが無かった場合」の処理がうまくいきません

例
　太郎　10点
　花子　8点

ここに太郎を11点で上書きするのは平気ですが
「三郎　9点」　を足そうとするとエラーになります。

追加したい処理は　「IDが既存になかった場合にそのIDで新しく登録を行う」です。

または　「IDで検索を行い、それがあるか否かを返す」関数が知りたいです。
サンプルを参考に書いた次のコードですが条件が「エラーがなかった」であり
「検索結果があっか」になっていないのが問題だと思うからです。

```
    /// <summary>
    /// NCMBへスコアを記録 スコア(float) ゲーム名
    /// </summary>
public static void saveScore(float score,string game){
    Debug.Log ("score:"+score+",game:"+game);
    string id = PlayerPrefs.GetString (RegisterID.UID, "");//固有のIDを呼び出す
    NCMBQuery<NCMBObject> query = new NCMBQuery<NCMBObject> (game);
    query.WhereEqualTo ("id",id);//id をキーに検索
    query.FindAsync ((List<NCMBObject> objList ,NCMBException e) => {
        //検索成功したら   
        if (e == null) {
            Debug.Log ("検索OK");
            objList[0]["Score"] = score;
            objList[0].SaveAsync();
        }else{
        //検索結果がない場合、次のログを吐き出さずにエラーになる               Debug.Log("saveScore:err");
            NCMBObject obj = new NCMBObject(game);
            obj["id"]  = PlayerPrefs.GetString(RegisterID.UID,"");
            obj["Name"]  = PlayerPrefs.GetString(RegisterID.NAME,"");
            obj["Score"] = score;
            obj.SaveAsync();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://mb.cloud.nifty.com/doc/current/tutorial/unity_highscore.html

実際に試していないので合っているか分かりませんが
上記ドキュメントを見る限り`FindAsync`の結果を`e == null`チェックした後、
`objList.Count==0`で未登録を確認できるようです。